# Evaluate an expression containing relational and logical operators in c#

Tags: c#

Evaluate an expression containing relational and logical operators in c#
For eg:

`(((a>b)&&(c<d))||(a==b))`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Ok, I've done it. What now?